# Por qué no puedo leer un objeto de una clase llamado desde otra clase

Tags: android, poo, android-volley

Tengo el siguiente problema: intento crear un objeto nuevo "CamionAsignado" en una clase, a partir de otra clase padre llamado "vehículos", pero me devuelve "null" en el método getter correspondiente. Este sería un resumen de mi código:

**Clase Vehículos**:

```
public class Vehiculos extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String codVehiculo;
    private String nombreVehiculo;
   
    private int usuario;

    public Vehiculos(int usuario){
        this.usuario = usuario;        
    }


    // GETTERS Y SETTERS
    public String getCodVehiculo() {
        return codVehiculo;
    }

    public void setCodVehiculo(String codVehiculo) {
        this.codVehiculo = codVehiculo;
    }

    public String getNombreVehiculo() {
        return nombreVehiculo;
    }

    public void setNombreVehiculo(String nombreVehiculo) {
        this.nombreVehiculo = nombreVehiculo;
    }

//Clase que asigna un vehículo a un conductor. La conexión al webservice y los métodos funcionan bien.
public void asignaCamion(){

        String url = "URL/obtVehiculoAsignado.php";

        StringRequest eventfulRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                                JSONArray datos = jsonObject.getJSONArray("datos");

                                String codVehic = "";
                                String nomVehic = "";
                                

                                for (int i = 0; i < datos.length(); i++) {

                                    codVehic = datos.getJSONObject(i).getString("COD_VEHICULO");
                                    nomVehic = datos.getJSONObject(i).getString("DESCRIPCION");                                 
                                }

                                setCodVehiculo(codVehic);
                                setNombreVehiculo(nomVehic);
                                System.out.println(getCodVehiculo) //<--Esto me funciona bien


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {                      
                    }
                }) {


            //Parámetros de la petición POST
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("cod_usuario", String.valueOf(usuario));
                return params;
            }
        };

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(eventfulRequest);
    }
}
```

**Clase CamionAsignado**

```
public class CamionAsignado extends BaseActivity {
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camion_asignado);

    Vehiculos vehiculo1 = new Vehiculos(codUser); //Paso de parámetro 

    vehiculo1.asignaCamion(); //llamada al método que asigna un vehículo a un conductor

    System.out.println(vehiculo1.getCodVehiculo()); //<--Aquí me devuelve Null

}

}
```

Es decir, en la primera clase "Vehículos" me genera bien el objeto y puedo leer sus getters bien. El problema es cuando intento leer esos mismos getters desde otra clase diferente.

No sé a qué se puede deber el error. Muchas gracias.

Comment: El problema es que asignaCamion es una función asíncrona, por lo que System.out.println(vehiculo1.getCodVehiculo()); se ejecuta antes de que vehiculo1.asignaCamion() termine.

Comment: Vaya. Entonces cómo podría establecer un orden? No usando Volley o algo así?